# Multiple Configurations for Linux usb install to use on multiple machines

Tags: linux, debian, configuration-managment

The title might be a little cryptic.

I have a Debian base install on a usb drive. This drive is meant to be used on an array of computers with various keyboard layouts and other hardware.

Is there anyway to save a “configuration” for reuse with a specific piece of hardware? Say computer A has a us keyboard layout and needs a proprietary driver for something. Can I configure these then save the data (or save the configuration) so that next time I connect the usb to it it will remember to use these settings?

Obviously if I do the same for computers B,C, and D I would like te proper keyboard layouts and driver setup for those computers.

Comment: I think `Rsync` should help you out (https://www.ostechnix.com/backup-entire-linux-system-using-rsync/)

Comment: I'm not really looking to save the entire system. Just configuration.

Comment: I have a homemade solution working atm but it involves a bit of `visudo` work so I'm not all that excited about it. It's also a partial solution right now.